# Replacing element inside a Collection by using regular expressions

Tags: java, string, collections, replaceall

I have a `Collection` of strings.

I need to replace some characters with given relevant characters.

I was tried this. But my code but doesn't work correctly.

```
public class MyPattern {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String items;
        Collection<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("I00.30");  //Expected output: 100.30
        arr.add("8B4.99");  //Expected output: 884.99
        arr.add("B37.2B");  //Expected output: 837.28
        arr.add("292.b4");  //Expected output: 262.64
        arr.add("24|.7O");  //Expected output: 241.70
        arr.add("B55.I4");  //Expected output: 855.14
        arr.add("444.07");  //Expected output: 444.07

        for(String item:arr)
        {
            System.out.println(item);
            items = item.toUpperCase().replaceAll("l", "1")
                .replaceAll("l", "1")
                .replaceAll("i", "1")
                .replaceAll("|", "1")
                .replaceAll("G", "6")
                .replaceAll("b", "6")
                .replaceAll("B", "8")
                .replaceAll("O", "0");
            System.out.println(items);
        }
    }
}
```

The letters passed in the `replaceAll()` method has to be replaced in every item in the *collection*.

Is there any way to find the irrelevant character and replace it with the number (*as shown in the code above*) ?

Comment: I can't understand the last paragraph of your question, but there is no reason to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` here; you are not using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is resigning the variable `item`, it will not affect the list contents.

To be able to do that, you might change the type of variable `arr` to `List`. With that, you can iterate over it by using the traditional (*index based*) `for` loop.

```
List<String> arr = // initializing the list

for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
    String item = replace(arr.get(i)); // method replace provided below
    arr.set(i, item);
}
```

Another option is to use **Java 8** `replaceAll()` method, which expects a ***function*** that will be applied to every element in the collection.

```
arr.replaceAll(str -> replace(str));
```

```
public static String replace(String source) {
    return source.toUpperCase()
            .replaceAll("[LI|]", "1")
            .replaceAll("[GB]", "6")
            .replace("O", "0");
}
```

***Note*** that method `replaceAll()` that expect a *regular expression* is more expensive than `replace()`. Hence, when you don't need a *regex*, its better to use any flavor of `replace()` (with either `char` or `String` arguments).

Here you can benefit from `replaceAll()` by processing characters `L`, `L` and `|` in one go with a regular expression `"[LI|]"`.

[*For more information on regular expressions take a look at this tutorial*](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

There's also a *minor issue* in your code:

- After `toUpperCase()` has been applied, it doesn't make sense to try to replace lowercase letters like 'l' or 'i'.
- There's a clash `"b", "6"` and `"B", "8"`.

I hope with all these hints you'll be able to manage to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the `for` loop. You can use, `stream`.
For example, if you want to change `i` to `1` in every element, you can get it using the following code. And you want to

```
Collection<String> arr_new = arr.stream().map(String::toLowerCase).map(t->t.replaceAll("i",1)).map(String::toUpperCase);
```

Here, the first map converts the String to lower-case, the second map do replace what you need and the third map convert it to the upper case.
I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Your code will not compile because you are trying to assign *not terminated stream* to a *collection*. And the usage streams is redundant here because it can be substituted by applying `replaceAll()` on the *collection*.